# Opening a View as Dialog box in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to open edit and delete views of my MVC app to open in a dialog box but don't have idea how to do it. Here is my code in Index View:

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { @item.PersonID }) 
      <a href='javascript:test(@item.PersonID);'> Edit </a>
```

and here is the java script method

```
  function test(x){

    var url = '@Url.Action("Edit1","Default1")';
    url = url + "?PersonID=" + x;

    $('#div_res').load(url);


}
```

I am using a PartialView named "Edit1" and I want to show that partial view in a dialog box.
I have tried it like that:

```
 alert( $('#div_res').load(url));
```

But it didn't worked for me.

Comment: I suggest you evaluate some third party libraries that provide that kind of functionality (jqModal, Twitter Bootstrap...)

Comment: thanks @MauroCerutti, i used reveal and it works great ... :)